# What is the difference between creating a vector with c() and as.vector?

Tags: r, vector

I would like to create a **vector**, **numeric vector** to be specific in R Studio. I met these two while reading some matters about R. I am quite confused about the difference between the two. Which should I use or which is better?

```
 mydata <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

and

```
 mydata <- as.vector(c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Comment: Try typing `?as.vector` in to the console for more information. It's more for coercing data from another data type in to a vector. `is.vector(c(1,2,3,4,5))` returns TRUE so no need to include `as.vector`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to call `as.vector`, as `c()` will create vector with the given entries. `as.vector(c(1,2,3))` would try to coerce a vector to a vector, and will do nothing in this case.

You can see that both have the same type with `str()`, e.g.

```
> str(c(1,2,3))
 num [1:3] 1 2 3
> str(as.vector(c(1,2,3)))
 num [1:3] 1 2 3
```

Both will evaluate to a numeric vector.

The manual might be able to explain some more. You can look up help text for (most) functions by prepending a `?` to the function name.

```
?c
```

> This is a generic function which combines its arguments.
>
> The default method combines its arguments to form a vector. All
> arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the
> returned value, and all attributes except names are removed.

The type of the vector will depend on the input you are giving it. If you are providing `c()` with numeric values, it will be a numeric vector, and the same for strings. Note that mixing types in vectors may have undesired consequences, as a vector can only have one type.

```
?as.vector
```

> as.vector, a generic, attempts to coerce its argument into a vector of
> mode mode (the default is to coerce to whichever vector mode is most
> convenient): if the result is atomic all attributes are removed.

Notice that I wrote "in this case" for `as.vector(c(1,2,3))`. If you had a named vector calling `as.vector()` would remove the names, e.g.

```
> vec = c("abc" = 2, "def" = 3)
> vec
abc def 
  2   3 
> as.vector(vec)
[1] 2 3
```

Notice that the names are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the result with `dput` if in doubt:

```
dput( c(1,2,3,4,5) )
dput( as.vector(c(1,2,3,4,5) ))
```

It gives you the R-code necessary to recreate them. They should come out identical.

as.vector turns *it's first argument* into a vector, and offers additional functionality with the `mode`argument. `c` combines *multiple arguments*, coercing them to a common type. The manuals have examples and further documetnation `?c` and `?as.vector`

Comment: Thank you. I tried the ? function for the both but I cannot clearly understand what does it says. But, it is clear to me somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is in the attribute `names`.

From the help pages `help('as.vector')`, my emphasis:

> **as.vector**, a generic, attempts to coerce its argument into a vector of mode mode (the default is to coerce to whichever vector mode is most convenient): **if the result is atomic all attributes are removed**.

and `help('c')`, my emphasis:

> The default method combines its arguments to form a vector. All arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the returned value, and **all attributes except names are removed**.

```
mydata <- setNames(c(1,2,3,4,5), letters[1:5])

c(mydata)
#a b c d e 
#1 2 3 4 5 

as.vector(mydata)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```